# Avoiding iframe getting overlapped by bootstrap column

Tags: html, css, iframe

I am trying to embed some widgets in iframes. I am using bootstrap.
In this page a bootstrap row contains two columns which occupy half of page for viewport `md`+ and full page for less than `md`. Also the widgets in this row needs larger height. So I added `style="height: 200%;"` to `iframes`

I built following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <title>Bootstrap Page</title>
  <style>
    .iframe-container {
      position: relative;
      padding-bottom: 56.25%;
      overflow: hidden;
      max-width: 100%;
    }

    .iframe-container iframe {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row" style="padding-bottom: 160px;">
      <div class="col-md-6 col-12 pr-1 mt-1">
        <div class="iframe-container">
          <iframe src="https://example.com/" style="height: 400%;"></iframe>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6 col-12 pl-1 mt-1">
        <div class="iframe-container">
          <iframe src="https://example.com/" style="height: 400%;"></iframe>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

When webpage size is less than `md`, it gets rendered as follows:

[image]

Note that if you click first column iframe in developer tools, the preview shows how iframe in first column gets overlapped by iframe in second column. How can I avoid this?

(You can view this example in action [on this codesandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/double-height-row-o2t0hh?file=/index.html))

PS: For example.com, its not an issue, but for my widget, it is!

Comment: I don't see how we can possibly help you without having the actual widget to see how it's affected the page code-wise or at least a link to the documentation of said widget.